# put pageview inside listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn how to create complex UI elements in flutter and faced this problem. Suppose I want to put a pageview in my listView and display the same items as in the horizontal scrolling list. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code of build method with listview:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _catList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(_catList[index].name),
                ),
              ),
              IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column (
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text ('ID: ${_catList[index].id}'),
                          Text ('Country code: ${_catList[index].countryCodes}'),
                          Text ('Temperament: ${_catList[index].temperament}'),
                          Text ('Origin: ${_catList[index].origin}')
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Text(_catList[index].description),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container (
                child: PageView.builder (itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                } ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As i under stand you want to add `PageView` in side `ListView`. So your `ListView` scroll in vertical direction and your `PageView` scroll in horizontal direction.  If i am not wrong then below is my code to do the same things.

I have made my `List` which contain multiple `List` like below.

```
var modelListOne = ["model_1_1.png", "model_1_2.png",];
var modelListTwo = ["model_2_1.png", "model_2_2.png",];

var modelList = [modelListOne, modelListTwo,];

return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: modelList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => YOURPAGE());
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 350,
                            width: double.maxFinite,
                            child: PageView.builder(
                                itemCount: modelList[index].length,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemBuilder: (context, pageIndex) {
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 300,
                                    width: double.maxFinite,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                              "assets/images/${modelList[index][pageIndex]}",
                                            ),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                  );
                                }),
                          )),
                    ),
                  );
                });
```

Make changes regarding to your requirements. Thanks.